# CodeIgniter HMVC object_to_array() error

Tags: php, codeigniter, hmvc-codeigniter

HMVC : https://bitbucket.org/wiredesignz/codeigniter-modular-extensions-hmvc/downloads

After downloading CI and copying over the HMVC, I'm getting the following error:

> An uncaught Exception was encountered
>
> Type: Error
>
> Message: Call to undefined method MY_Loader::_ci_object_to_array()
>
> Filename:
>   /Users/k1ut2/Sites/nine.dev/application/third_party/MX/Loader.php
>
> Line Number: 300
>
> Backtrace:
>
> File: /Users/k1ut2/Sites/nine.dev/application/controllers/Welcome.php
>   Line: 23 Function: view
>
> File: /Users/k1ut2/Sites/nine.dev/index.php Line: 315 Function:
>   require_once

Comment: You need create it in `application > modules > your_module > controllers > Welcome.php `

Comment: Old but good tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8fy8E_C5_qQ

Comment: I did create it correctly, if the original Welcome file is eliminated the same error is returned

Comment: `File: /Users/k1ut2/Sites/nine.dev/application/controllers/Welcome.php Line: 23 Function: view` this in error

Comment: Try yourself, download the latest and include HMVC. I've created the files, just forgot to delete the old ones. But after deletion the same error is returned. I even renamed the view required and function in the controller and no success

Answer (score 111, accepted):

Just adding this here as the Link provided by Clasyk isn't currently working...

The short version from that thread boils down to this...

In application/third_party/MX/Loader.php you can do the following...

Under `public function view($view, $vars = array(), $return = FALSE)` Look for... (Line 300)

```
return $this->_ci_load(array('_ci_view' => $view, '_ci_vars' => $this->_ci_object_to_array($vars), '_ci_return' => $return));
```

Replace this with

```
if (method_exists($this, '_ci_object_to_array'))
{
        return $this->_ci_load(array('_ci_view' => $view, '_ci_vars' => $this->_ci_object_to_array($vars), '_ci_return' => $return));
} else {
        return $this->_ci_load(array('_ci_view' => $view, '_ci_vars' => $this->_ci_prepare_view_vars($vars), '_ci_return' => $return));
}
```

It's the result of a "little" undocumented change that the CI Devs implemented, which is fine!

There is a pull request on Wiredesignz awaiting action so he knows about it...

In the meantime, you can implement the above "diddle" and get back to coding :)

Comment: Your if() is missing the underscore - should be _ci_object_to_array

Comment: sneaky undocumented feature... thanks for the quick fix code, saved me some debug time.

Comment: Very Nice Solution. Worked for me. Thanks

Comment: wow, great solution. I was face same problem. Now my system is ok.

Comment: Turning to warn that the problem persists to this day, in Wiredesignz did not pull request of this correction.

Answer (score 5):

*I got the solution.this is working for me.
 On Line 300 of application/third_party/MX/Loader.php*

This line generates an error with CI 3.1.3

```
return $this->_ci_load(array('_ci_view' => $view, '_ci_vars' => $this->_ci_object_to_array($vars), '_ci_return' => $return));
```

Replace with this line.

```
return $this->_ci_load(array('_ci_view' => $view, '_ci_vars' => $this->_ci_prepare_view_vars($vars), '_ci_return' => $return));
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Found this Use this place in application / core / MY_Loader.php

From here https://bitbucket.org/wiredesignz/codeigniter-modular-extensions-hmvc/pull-requests/17/fix-loaderphp-for-ci-313/diff#comment-30560940

```
<?php (defined('BASEPATH')) OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

/* load the MX_Loader class */
require APPPATH."third_party/MX/Loader.php";

class MY_Loader extends MX_Loader
{
    /** Load a module view **/
    public function view($view, $vars = array(), $return = FALSE)
    {
        list($path, $_view) = Modules::find($view, $this->_module, 'views/');

        if ($path != FALSE)
        {
            $this->_ci_view_paths = array($path => TRUE) + $this->_ci_view_paths;
            $view = $_view;
        }

        return $this->_ci_load(array('_ci_view' => $view, '_ci_vars' => ((method_exists($this,'_ci_object_to_array')) ? $this->_ci_object_to_array($vars) : $this->_ci_prepare_view_vars($vars)), '_ci_return' => $return));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

HMVC doesn't work with 3.1.3 (current version). But works with all versions up to 3.1.2. Just tested this myself from 3.0.0 upwards.

Comment: Good point I have now asked on the codeigniter forum. I tested it out you are right.

Comment: As pointed in the forum link, changing `$this->_ci_object_to_array($vars)` to `$this->_ci_prepare_view_vars($vars)` in "application\third_party\MX\Loader.php" on line 300 worked. Thanks

Comment: Somehow the error  is there on 3.1.11. 
Along with strpos() error on line 239 (MX/Router.php)

Answer (score 1):

Add this lines in application/third_party/MX/Loader.php after line 307,

```html
protected function _ci_object_to_array($object) 
 {
    return is_object($object) ? get_object_vars($object) : $object;
    }
```

However for 3.1.3 HMVC doesn't work.

better luck.